# are there compatibility issues with android 4.4.2 and css3 grid

Tags: android, css, cordova

I have written an app using javascript, css, html. It works fine on android 7.1.1 but does not display the grid correctly on android 4.4.2

I have gone to w3c and copied and pasted their sample of how a simple grid works, it doesn't work either on android 4.4.2

```
    .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}



    <div class='grid-container' >

    <div  class="grid-item" >1</div>

    <div  class="grid-item" >2</div>

    <div  class="grid-item" >3</div>

    </div>
```

on android 7.1.1 a single row of 3 columns is displayed.
on android 4.4.2 3 rows with 1 column in row is displayed.

Comment: Seems like it. See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_ and https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid

Comment: it *probably* depends on a web browser, not Android version